# How to access web content protected by network ip?

Tags: network, ip, ip-spoofing

I am testing a website that allows content fetch only when you access it from an IP a certain Wi-Fi network. However if you want to access the website from different network, you get the response of

`{"error":"IP access failed."}`

I want to test to see if someone can still access the website if they spoof the network's IP. How could someone spoof an IP?

I want to run those tests on the backend myself to see if I could access data.

Comment: You need to look up "ip spoofing" and how to set a manual IP in your operating system. There is a ton of resources for this online since it is a very common thing. The problem you will run into is that if you spoof an IP, you will pass the check on the server, but the server will send the content to the real IP, not what you spoofed. Please look up all the posts here on that topic.

Comment: This is likely what you need: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/245267/can-i-change-my-public-ip-address-to-a-specific-one but question this really is a networking question, not a security question.